# Adding custom module or view to MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack, meanjs

How do I go about switching out the "core" module as the default view? There are four modules: "articles", "chat", "core", and "users" but I want to create my own custom view from scratch.

Comment: the MEAN stack is a group of 4 different client/server libraries which are used together.  There are no "article", "chat", "core", or "users" specific to the MEAN stack.  Perhaps you are asking about a template that was generated to make use of the stack?

Comment: Yes, I know the MEAN stack is four libraries. I cloned it from here: https://github.com/meanjs/mean. The view it loads by default is the 'core' module. I was wondering to change this, and have it render my own template by default.

Comment: So your question is about how to modify a template based on the stack then.  fully modifying the template would involve making changes to code for at least 2-3, but probably all 4 of the different libraries.  Have you gone through any of the documentation or the tutorials? and if so, which portion are you having trouble with?  posting code and a specific problem will be more helpful than just asking for someone to rewrite the documentation as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to ask is how to use `Express` rendering a template ?
It's not about `MEAN stack`, it's about how to use `Express`.

If your MEAN project starts from an existing project, you may find `View` directory, add your own view templates to this directory,and then maybe you need to add some route code in `Controller` level.